# Spring Boot WebMvcTest with custom filter difficulties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, dependency-injection, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I'm using JWT authentication via custom filter that uses several `@Service`s.

like so

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthentiationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final UserService;
    ...
}
```

(I'm autowiring the services in the constructor)

Now, I have a controller that I want to test:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(...)
public class COmputerDeviceController {

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('devices)")
    public List<Device> getDevices() {
         ...
    }
}
```

I wanted to test the controller & security, like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ComputerDeviceController.class)
public class ComputerDeviceControllerTest {

     @Autowired
     private MockMvc mvc;

     @WithMockUser
     @Test
     public void test() throws Exception {
         ...
     }
}
```

The problem arises from the use of the filter - when trying to run the test, I get `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`(No qualifying bean of type `UserService` available)

I know I can run it as an integration test, but really it just tests the controller and there isn't a need for that, aside for the custom filter & Spring Security.

How can I solve this? I've tried different solutions, like adding `@ComponentScan.Filter`, and included dependencies manually, but in the end I have to provide `entitymanager`, which doesn't seems right.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) , `@WebMvcTes` will register `JwtAuthentiationFilter` as the spring bean but not its dependencies , you have to use  `@MockBean` to declare these dependencies.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ComputerDeviceController.class)
public class ComputerDeviceControllerTest {

     @Autowired
     private MockMvc mvc;

     @MockBean
     private UserService userService;

     @WithMockUser
     @Test
     public void test() throws Exception {
        //Then you can stub userService behaviour here.. 
     }
}
```

The same applied to all dependencies of all bean that are auto registered as spring beans by `@WebMvcTest` which includes `@Controller`, `@ControllerAdvice`, `@JsonComponent`, `Converter`, `GenericConverter`, `Filter`, `WebMvcConfigurer`, and `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

Comment: Is there another way to approach this? I have another service which handles the JWT data, and there's really no need to mock or mess with it, as it is completely technical. Should I make that service static, instead? (It doesn't *have* to be used with DI, right?)

Comment: Not sure. `@MockBean` approach is very make sense when come to unit testing a Controller because in the end , you still have to mock all of its dependencies. So what is your concern actually when using `@MockBean`  ?